# how to solve kivy widget error "only one root object is allowed by .kv"

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

First I want to say I just started learning maybe 2 months ago so I don't really know how to phrase my question. so if the Question title is misleading I'm sorry.

basically I'm working on a project and I want to learn how to add projects I've already done inside an like the pong game (pong.py and pong.kv) I made and I want to see if I can use the simple app (main.py, main.kv, playscreen.kv, settingscreen.kv, aboutscreen.kv)I made to run the pong game. Basically I'm trying to make the main app be able to navigate to the playscreen and then be able to play pong

I cant even remember all the things I've tried but when I think I get close I end up seeing a black screen or I just see the pong screen which is the problem I'm having now.

**Main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AboutScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PlayScreen(Screen):
    pass

class PlayPong(Screen):
    pass





#GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"



    def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        ScreenManager.transition
        #screen_manager.play_pong = Builder.load_file("kv/pong.py")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Main.kv**

```
#:include kv/homescreen.kv
#:include kv/settingscreen.kv
#:include kv/aboutscreen.kv
#:include kv/playscreen.kv
#:include kv/playpong.kv


GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        SettingScreen:
            name: "setting_screen"
            id: setting_screen
        AboutScreen:
            name:"about_screen"
            id: about_screen
        PlayScreen:
            name:"play_screen"
            id: play_screen
        PlayPong:
            name: "play_pong"
            id: "play_pong"
```

**playpong.kv**

```
#:import PongApp kv.pong.PongApp
#:import App kivy.app.App

<PlayPong>:

#PongApp().run()
```

**homescreen.kv**

```
#:include kivymd/MDApp.py
#:include kivymd/uix/button.py/MDFloatingActionButton/MDFlatButton
#:include kivymd/uix/screen.py/Screen
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.uix.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import Builder kivy.lang.Builder

<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .95, "center_y": .97}
                title: 'Main Menu'
                elevation:10
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: x]]
                right_action_items: [["book", lambda x: x]]

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            size_hint: .8,.1
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            text: "Settings"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("setting_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .8,.1
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            text: "about"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("about_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
            size_hint: .8,.1
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            text: "play"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("play_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

**playscreen.kv**

```
<PlayScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .95, "center_y": .95}
                title: 'Game Menu'
                elevation:10
                left_action_items: [["devices", lambda x: x]]
                right_action_items: [["gesture", lambda x: x]]
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .6,.1
            text: "Main Menu"
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("home_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            size_hint: .6,.1
            text: "Play Pong"
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("play_pong")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

**settingscreen.kv**

```
#:include kivymd/MDApp.py
#:include kivymd/uix/button.py/MDFloatingActionButton/MDFlatButton
#:include kivymd/uix/screen.py/Screen
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.uix.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import Builder kivy.lang.Builder


<SettingScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .95, "center_y": .95}
                title: 'Settings'
                left_action_items: [["settings", lambda x: x]]
                right_action_items: [["dns", lambda x: x]]
                elevation:10
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .6,.1
            text: "Main Menu"
            md_bg_color: [.200,.150,.150,.3]
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("home_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

**aboutscreen.kv**

```
<AboutScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDToolbar:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .95, "center_y": .95}
                title: 'About The Game and Creator'
                elevation:10
                left_action_items: [["emoticon", lambda x: x]]
                right_action_items: [["library", lambda x: x]]
        Label:
            pos_hint: {"top":.9 , "left":.5}
            size_hint: 1,.2
            text:
                "About the app and the creator"
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .6,.1
            text: "Main Menu"
            on_release:
                app.change_screen("home_screen")
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

**pong.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint

class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)
    def bounce_ball(self,ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            ball.velocity_x *= -1.1

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x,velocity_y)
# latest postion = Current velocity + Current Position
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

# moving the ball by calling move function
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0,360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        # bounce off top and bottom
        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.y > self.height -30):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

            # bounce off left and increase score
        if self.ball.x < -30:
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
            self.player1.score += 1

        # bounce of right
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.ball.velocity_x *= -1
            self.player2.score += 1



        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 1/4:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width * 3/4:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update,0/60.0)
        return game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PongApp().run()
```

**pong.kv**

```
<PongPaddle>:
    size: 20,200
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size



<PongBall>:
    size: 30,30
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>:
    ball : pong_ball
    player1 : player_left
    player2 : player_right
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 30
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3/4
        top: root.top - 30
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    PongBall:
        id : pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id:player_left
        x : root.x
        center_y : root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id:player_right
        x : root.width - self.width
        center_y : root.center_y
```

So after I updated my app I'm still getting a widget error

```
 1:from kivy.app import App
 >>    2:from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
       3:from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
       4:from kivy.vector import Vector
 ...
 Only one root object is allowed by .kv
```

Ive tried playing with the classes to try and only make one widget but then that messes up the code and I get other errors

I've also tried writing all the Pong.py code into my Main.py file but that didn't seem to work either.
Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: The `Screen` displayed will be the `HomeScreen`, but you haven't shown te contents of `homescreen.kv`.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and just put everything.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are seeing the pong game is because of the line:

```
PongApp().run()
```

Which starts the pong game as soon as you import that file.

Replace that line with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PongApp().run()
```

That protects the running of `PongApp` unless `pong.py` is run directly by python, and not just imported.

Comment: yeah that seemed to work but now I'm getting an Error
...
       1:from kivy.app import App
 >>    2:from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
       3:from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
       4:from kivy.vector import Vector
 ...
 Only one root object is allowed by .kv.

Comment: In your `homescreen.kv` and `settingscreen.kv` you have `#:include` statements that include files that are not `kv` files. Start by removing them. The `#:import` statements are fine, but only `kv` files can be included.  If that doesn't fix it, then remove the `self.root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")` line from `main.py`, since it will be automatically loaded.